# Replacing tied rank by their average

Tags: r, ranking

I have the following dataframe:

```
> x
  tags freq.Freq
1    a       740
2    b       722
3    c       722
4    d       541
5    e       525
6    f       525
7    g       525
8    h       326
9    i       296
```

i.e.

```
x<- structure(list(tags = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
 freq.Freq = c(740L, 722L, 722L, 541L, 525L, 525L, 525L, 326L, 296L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

I would like to replace the column `freq.Freq` by ranking of each letter in `tags`. E.g., `a` is 1, `d` is 4, `i` is 9. Anyway, `b`, `c`, and `e`, `f`, `g` have the same ranks. For these cases I would like to replace `freq.Freq` by the average of "tied" ranks. In this way the desired output is:

```
  tags freq.Freq
1    a       1
2    b       2.5
3    c       2.5
4    d       4
5    e       6
6    f       6
7    g       6
8    h       8
9    i       9
```

My attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
min_rank(x$freq.Freq)
```

gives a wrong result:

```
9 7 7 6 3 3 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `rank` from `base R`.  The default method for `ties.method` is "average"

```
x$freq.Freq <- rank(-x$freq.Freq)
x$freq.Freq
#[1] 1.0 2.5 2.5 4.0 6.0 6.0 6.0 8.0 9.0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x %>%
    mutate(rank = match(tags, letters)) %>%
    group_by(freq.Freq) %>%
    mutate(rank = mean(rank)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Or a base R version as suggested by [markus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607746/replacing-tied-rank-by-their-average/60607780#comment107226009_60607780)

```
transform(x, new = ave(match(tags, letters), freq.Freq, FUN = mean))
```

Comment: Just saw your post which is what I had in mind too. Maybe you could add base R option: `transform(x, new = ave(match(tags, letters), freq.Freq, FUN = mean))`